# Flutter application showing error as: Error: [firebase_auth/configuration-not-found]

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Unable to connect firebase authentication to our flutter project . It is showing that :
nectar authentication Firebase in Flutter

User
showing this error:
Performing hot restart...                                          512ms
Restarted application in 515ms.
Error: [firebase_auth/configuration-not-found] Error
dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw*
packages/firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart 234:7                       createUserWithEmailAndPassword
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 60:31            
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1666:54                                          runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 171:22                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 852:46                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 873:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 649:5                                     [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 739:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15

Performing hot restart...                                        1,005ms
Restarted application in 1,006ms.
Error: [firebase_auth/configuration-not-found] Error
dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw*
packages/firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart 234:7                       createUserWithEmailAndPassword
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 60:31            
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1666:54                                          runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 171:22                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 852:46                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 873:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 649:5                                     [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 739:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15

I am sending email and password for signup but it is showing error here like this in terminal. And unable to connect firebase auth

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.